# How to know whether the Orientation of the screen have changed or not when extends an AppWidgetProvider?

Tags: android, widget, wifi

I am trying to create an WiFi widget for ICS supported devices. In ICS home screen orientation is supported, so while changing the orientation my widget becomes inactive(hanged). By doing the research I found that we need to re-assign the remoteView while changing the orientation. How to found whether the orientation have changed or not?.
If I am extending the activity then I have Overridden method onConfigurationChanged, but here i am extending AppWidgetProvider. How I can solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to update the RemoteViews on orientation change. RemoteViews is merely a sequence of commands that is applied to the widget's layout. When the orientation changes, the widget container recreates the layout (possibly using alternative layout and values if you use res/layout-land) and applies the RemoteViews commands to it. Try this, have your phone in landscape and add your widget to to the home screen, if it is not displayed than your have a problem somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an application to override `onConfigurationChanged` method:

```
public class WifiApp extends Application {
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    //here u can check the ori
}
...
```

Comment: will this tell you if the device orientation changed or if the home orientation changed? (since the home orientation change can be disable, they are not the same). I presume that the OP needs the later.